# Xcode 14 removes shortcut for comment selection on European keyboards

Tags: xcode, xcode14

[image]

Normally the shortcut is "⌘⇧/".

But being that "/" is on the "7" key on a Danish keyboard, this shortcut now opens the Help menu - ironically.

Manually adding it as a key binding does not help.

[image]

As far as I remember, the exact same thing happened last year with Xcode 13.

Comment: Just wondering why I couldn't comment a line anymore, changing Comment Selection to CMD+SHIFT+7 like in your screenshot, worked for me. I'm using an Italian keyboard.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: On xCode 14.0 (14A309), I got "⌘:" shortcut

Comment: In Xcode 14.1, I'm not able to change shortcut at all. Do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a french AZERTY keyboard I was able to fix it by going to:

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab > App Shortcuts > Uncheck `Show help Menu` in App Shortcuts

[image]

You'll still need to **Manually add it as a key binding**

Comment: The command is now ⌘ + ´. But I had to remove Show Help Menu like @ahbou pointed out and then change it back to ⌘ + SHIFT + / .

Comment: Thanks. This is the root cause of the problem, at least in my spanish keyboard

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue. I unchecked **adapt to current keyboard**. Now it's working as before. I am using a german keyboard.

Comment: I think this one should be the accepted answer since the change doesn't affect all applications, is Xcode specific.

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: @Zappel are you using a German keyboard?

Comment: It works on italian keywords too. Thanks.

Comment: @adri567 Danish

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem on a French keyboard where ⌘⇧/ sometimes correctly commented my selection and sometimes opened a test pane on XCode. This was driving me nuts.

Comment: It should also be explicitly noted that you find the "adapt to current keyboard" option in the xcode settings panel on the key bindings tab.

Answer (score 4):

That's true. The way to comment on a whole code selection has been changed in Xcode 14.

On Spanish keyboards works by pressing `cmd` + `'`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkUg2.png)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Default 'comment selected' shortcut is cmd+*]

`CMD + *` worked for the Turkish keyboard.